# How to make 'a new list of tuple pairs' from 'a list of tuple pairs' with the most frequent tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

`lst = [('wish', 'NOUN'), ('wish', 'VERB'), ('this', 'DET'), ('this', 'DET'), ('this', 'PROPN'), ('Christmas', 'PROPN')]`

`word_l = ['this', 'wish', 'Christmas']`

The programs should find the words of 'word_l' in 'lst'. It should make a new list from the list of tuples 'lst' with the most frequent tuple based on those words. The new_list should contain,

`new_list = [('wish', 'NOUN'), ('this', 'DET'), ('Christmas', 'PROPN')]`

In the case where "wish" appears with "NOUN" once and with 'VERB' once, selecting any of them is fine. "this" should appear only with "DET". 'lst' is a long list of tuples like this.

Comment: Please format your code in code blocks, you can do that by using \`\`\` around the code.

Comment: This is a part of code. I just want to know how to do this part. How do you know it's my homework?

Comment: You only offer input and output and a broad definition of what your function should do, no skeleton or draft of that function, sounds like you want your homework done for you. Add in a base of code on which to improve and then SO will be the correct place to ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are wanting

```
lst = [('wish', 'NOUN'), ('wish', 'VERB'), ('this', 'DET'), ('this', 'DET'), ('this', 'PROPN'), ('Christmas', 'PROPN')]
word_l = ['this', 'wish', 'Christmas']
dict = {}
new_l =[]
def main():
    for x in lst:
        if not x in dict:
            dict[x]=1
        else:
            dict[x] += 1
    n=0
    p = ()
    for w in word_l:
        for key in dict:
            if key[0]==w and dict.get(key)>n:
                p = key
                n = dict.get(key)
        
        new_l.append(p)
        n=0
        p=()
    print(new_l)
    
main()
```